# simple for loop finishes and fails the run

Tags: c++, loops

For some unknown reason this simple code runs, does what it's expected to do and then crashes the run. I am using NetBeans IDE, which overlapped my arrays before (tends to be buggy), so I was wondering if someone gets the same error - that would mean I certainly have to change the IDE environment.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
int first[4][4];

for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < 5;b++)
    {
        cout << a << " " << b << " ";
        if (first [a][b] != 0)
        {    
            first[a][b] = 0;
        }
        cout << first[a][b] << "    ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
}


return 0;
};
```

Comment: is the main supposed to end with `;`? How is it even compiling? And actually, 99.99% of the time the error comes from you and not your IDE

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Your array needs to be size [5][5], or your for loops need to end at 4, you are trying to access memory that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the ide, I think your problem is probably in your loops, `for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)` should be `for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)`

Comment: You are accessing the array out of bounds.

Comment: @JacobH  You should post an answer.

Comment: This is what you get if you run the code:
0 0 0    0 1 0    0 2 0    0 3 0    0 4 0 
1 0 0    1 1 0    1 2 0    1 3 0    1 4 0    


2 0 0    2 1 0    2 2 0    2 3 0    2 4 0    


3 0 0    3 1 0    3 2 0    3 3 0    3 4 0    


4 0 0    4 1 0    4 2 0    4 3 0    4 4 0
it runs and compiles, I'm not accessing memory that doesn't belong to me

Comment: @chocc If you have `4` elements the maximum index will be `3`. `< 5` takes `a` and `b` to `4` which is beyond the end of the array. This is undefined behavior. The program may now crash if it likes or it may make you some coffee. Whatever it likes to do.

Answer (score 3):

here you are declearing a array with 4 indexes.In c/c++ index number starts at 0.
In your code you are saying :

```
int first[4][4];
```

that means indexs are : 0 1 2 3.Array length or total index are 4.
But in for loop you are saying

```
for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
....
}
```

so you are trying to access index number 0 1 2 3 4 respectively.But remember you don't have index number 4.That is why it should give array index out of bound error.

Also at the end of main function you are using a semicolon.remove that

```
main () {
....
};
```

Hope this solves the problem.From next time Please try to provide details about the errors your IDE is giving you as it will be easier for the people who are giving answer.

Comment: thank you for clarification. I've been trying to get through my problems for past 10 hours and I was so tired I didn't see my stupid mistake.

Comment: I did not receive any errors or even warning from IDE; it just returned a few values that don't mean anything

Comment: Even if he did not put anything in the array this will work.Because by default array indexes have the value 0 in them.

Comment: Everything in a valid Java program not explicitly set to something by the programmer, is initialized to a zero value.

For references (anything that holds an object) that is null.
For int/short/byte/long that is a 0.
For float/double that is a 0.0
For booleans that is a false.
For char that is the null character '\u0000' (whose decimal equivalent is 0).

Comment: The problem is you will not receive any warning or error from IDE beforehand. Your code generated a run time exception. your IDE just checks the common things like semi colon and method perameter  etc.

Comment: @RatulBinTazul Actually they don't, this is C++ code and all the'values' at each index will just be garbage here, run time initialison isn't free.